# Where have all the Y-wings gone?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, vehicles, tactics

There is a significant battle in both *The Force Awakens* and *The Last Jedi* that require heavy bombardment on an enemy target.

In *The Force Awakens* it is the attack on Star Killer base, and in *The Last Jedi* it is the attack on the Dreadnought-class Star Destroyer.

Both attacks are eventually successful, but one thing I noticed was in both assaults the fighters sent did not seem to have the right type of vehicle to effectively take on their target.  The attack on Star Killer base used primarily [X-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-wing_starfighter) fighters whose firepower did not seem heavy enough to penetrate the oscillator, while the [MG-100s](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MG-100_StarFortress_SF-17) seemed to be too slow/not maneuverable enough for the attack on the dreadnought.

So my first thought was, why not [Y-wings](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BTL-A4_Y-wing_assault_starfighter/bomber)? They had been used to great extent (mostly<sup>1</sup>) sucessfully during the battles of Scarif, Yavin IV, and Endor. They are described as an "effective marriage between speed and firepower" which would have made more powerful than the X-wing and faster than the MG-100. It seems like the perfect fight!

So what happened? Was the manufacturer shut down, were other ships upgraded to render the Y-wing ineffective, was it an out-of-universe reason....

**Where have all the Y-wings gone?<sup>2</sup>**

<sub>1 - Yes, I know the Y-wing did not make the killing blows on either Death Star, but they still were the *first* choice.</sub>

<sub>2 - To read to [this tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPR108kwNo4)</sub>

Comment: Now you have me humming "Where Have All the Flowers Gone"...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - glad to know I'm not the only one...

Comment: The Poe Dameron comic has a Y-Wing appearance as a two-seater craft for a mission. The pilots complain repeatedly that it is out of date and will get them killed. Don't have my books on me right now, but hopefully someone can find the issues.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I've got "I Need A Hero"  "Where have all the Y-Wings gooone, where are all the bombs"

Comment: @emerssso - Sure, because the Rebellion can afford to be picky ;-)

Comment: Without having a canonical answer, I assume that the Resistance Bombers have super-seeded the Y-Wing in the bombing roll. The Resistance and the First Order have been trading blows for a long time, so it's not illogical to assume that the Resistance's stock of left over rebellion Y-Wings was destroyed, or otherwise cannibalized for parts to keep other fighters going.

Comment: According to wookiepedia, the Y-wing series 4 bombers were considered military material  and were in use by the new republic by the time of TFA. my guess is the whole y-wing fleet blew up at hosnian and the resistance couldn't purchase new ones in time, in the end, we must remember the resistance had  only 6 MG100's and about a dozen X and A wings.

Comment: "At least one Y-Wing was in use by the Resistance, where it was used by Black Squadron in a mission to obtain footage of the First Order committing war crimes. The ship was chosen, despite its old age, due to it being one of the few armed ships on hand that could carry both a pilot and a passenger."

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Squadron_(Resistance)

Comment: Dr Strangeforce: Or how I learned to stop worrying and love the X-wing

Comment: Gone to [Jakku-based](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/BTL_Y-wing_starfighter#Jakku) desert junk-field [scavengers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rey_Skywalker#The_scavenger), every one. When will they ever learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the Rebellion, the Resistance was working with whatever ships it could find. Even the T-70 X-wings in its fleet were only in use because they were more common than T-85s:

> Anticipating a conflict with the mysterious First Order, New Republic representatives formed the Resistance, and began obtaining starfighters in preparation for war. Because used and decommissioned T-70 X-wing (sic) were both available, affordable, and remained highly reliable, Resistance agents discreetly obtained as many T-70s as they could. Eventually, the T-70 X-wing became the signature combat craft of the Resistance starfighter corps.
>
> [...]
>
> When the First Order destroyed the Hosnian system, they not only atomized countless lifeforms on five worlds but also most of the New Republic Defense Fleet, including most T-85 X-wings in the Republic Navy. Desperate to prevent the First Order from committing further atrocities, the Resistance scrambled to acquire any available starfighters. Although they managed to obtain more T-70 X-wings, they may never again see the T-85.
>
> <sub>[*Rebel Starfighters: Owners' Workshop Manual*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Starfighters_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual), p82 and p96</sub>

While the Rebellion-era Y-wings were 50 or more years old by the time of the sequel trilogy, there were also updated BTA-NR2 Y-wings in production, which were eventually used at the battle of Exegol:

[image: Screenshot of a Y-wing attacking a Star Destroyer in The Rise of Skywalker]

> By the time the Alliance defeated the Empire, most operational Y-wings were well over twenty years old, and were skeletons of the original Clone Wars-era armored models.
>
> After the Alliance transitioned to become the New Republic, Koensayr ultimately embraced its role in galactic revolution by restarting the Y-wing product line with the BTA-NR2 Y-wing.
>
> <sub>[*Rebel Starfighters: Owners' Workshop Manual*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Starfighters_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual), p110</sub>

Since this source describes the Resistance "scrambl[ing] to acquire any available starfighters" after the destruction of Hosnian, the implication is that the Resistance was only able to acquire Y-wings as they became available on the market, and only started doing so in earnest after the destruction of Hosnian in 34 ABY. This seems to be an in-universe explanation for why updated Y-wings appear in *The Rise of Skywalker* but not either of the earlier films.

Comment: Awesome find! I never noticed the Y-wings when watching Rise of Skywalker.

Answer (score 14):

The Y-Wing was an old and essentially obsolete design. The first *Rebels* episode of the third season, "Steps Into Shadow" set in 2 BBY, involved stealing Y-Wings that were in the process of being scrapped, and Hera considered them old then. The new trilogy is set 36 years after *that*.

Comment: But new X-wings designs were made, so much that they are not considered obsolete. Why does the same not ring true with Y-wings? The link on Wookiepedia says that the Y-wings were being scrapped because the *Empire* wasn't using snub-fighters with hyper-drives. The manufacturer then sold the Y-wings to planetary defense groups. The actual ships might have been old, but why were new ones not being produced (like the X-wing)?

Comment: Y-Wings were used in the Clone Wars, so by the time of the *Rebels* episode were at least a 20 year old design, while the X-Wings were new (their first canonical timeline appearance in 1 BBY, again in *Rebels*). Right now there's no indications how long Y-Wings continued to be used after the Battle of Endor, so they may have been retired immediately, they may have lasted another 30 years and were retired just before "The Force Awakens".

Comment: For a real-world equivalent, the F-14 Tomcat was in service with the US from 1974 to 2006, 32 years. The F/A-18 entered USN service in 1984, is still in service (34 years) and has another 15 years or so planned, and that's not counting the F/A-18E/F SuperHornet (into service 1999). Just like the Tomcat and Hornet have different operational lifespans, and just as the Hornet has a new model based on it while the Tomcat didn't, B-Wings and X-Wings could have been the same.

Comment: The poor Tomcat.... forever my favorite aircraft!

Answer (score -1):

The original trilogy xwings (T65 X wings) are old and outdated. The new trilogy uses T70 X wings which are newer, more effective fighters. If there is no newer model of Y wing, ordinance equipted T70s are likely more useful in those applications than outdated Y wings.  The BS 17 resistance bombers also clearly held enough bombs to take out the dreadnought. I do not believe any other rebel bomber had that capacity.